# OpenCV hangs when using multiprocessing on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

This code runs as expected, and gives the expected output

```
import multiprocessing
import cv2
import os

path = r"/home/pi/Desktop/calibration.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(path)

def cvtcolor(img):
    print "converting to gray ..."
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print "converted to gray"

if True:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='test',
                          target=cvtcolor,
                          kwargs={'img':image}
                                      )
    p.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='test',
                          target=cvtcolor,
                          kwargs={'img':image}
                                      )
    p2.start()
```

outputs:

```
converting to gray ...
converting to gray ...
converted to gray
converted to gray
```

However, this code hangs when executed

```
import multiprocessing
import cv2
import os

path = r"/home/pi/Desktop/calibration.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(path)

def cvtcolor(img):
    print "converting to gray ..."
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print "converted to gray"


cvtcolor(image)

if True:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='test',
                          target=cvtcolor,
                          kwargs={'img':image}
                                      )
    p.start()
```

the function executed in the main process proceeds, but the function executed in the "test" process hangs forever

```
converting to gray ...
converted to gray
converting to gray ...
```

I am using OpenCV version 3.2.0, installed as detailed [here](https://github.com/TechBubbleTechnologies/IoT-JumpWay-RPI-Examples/blob/master/_DOCS/2-Installing-OpenCV-3-2-0.md) on Raspbian Jessie (raspberry pi)

Does anyone has an explanation / solution for this?

Comment: Does adding `p.join()` at the end help? Sorry, I know little about Python.

Comment: No it does not help, I need it to be running in the background anyway

Comment: I met this error too..

Answer (score -2):

have a look at what is returned. If you try the BGR2GRAY directly, you will get an array with shape attribute same as input image but with only 1 color, e.g. gray. When you run the same function using multiprocessing you do not get an array returned. It will have no shape attribute, try printing the output to see what form it is in, then maybe reconstruct an image from this.